# linux kallsyms R symbol not showing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, system-calls

I wan't to find the kernel address of system call table.
I usually do this by grepping sys_call
but in one system, I can see the address
but in other, it doesn't show the entry.

```
root@ubuntu:~# cat /proc/kallsyms | grep sys_call
ffffffff8122aa90 t proc_sys_call_handler
ffffffff81726432 t ret_from_sys_call
ffffffff81726644 T int_ret_from_sys_call
ffffffff81728146 t sysexit_from_sys_call
ffffffff81728386 t sysretl_from_sys_call
ffffffff8172858e t ia32_ret_from_sys_call
**ffffffff81801400 R sys_call_table**
ffffffff81809cc0 R ia32_sys_call_table
root@ubuntu:~#
```

no system call table... why not showing the R type symbol??

```
/ $ cat /proc/kallsyms | grep sys_call
ffffffff8119c230 t proc_sys_call_handler
ffffffff817a1a57 t ret_from_sys_call
ffffffff817a1c50 T int_ret_from_sys_call
ffffffff817a2cb8 t sysexit_from_sys_call
ffffffff817a2ed8 t sysretl_from_sys_call
ffffffff817a30be t ia32_ret_from_sys_call
/ $ 
/ $
```

in what case does this could happen?
some advice would be nice
thank you

Comment: try with `root` user in the other system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the version of the kernel in both cases, check with `uname -r`.

This was initially exported in the earlier versions of the kernel 2.4.x. This initially had "EXPORT_SYMBOL(sys_call_table);" line from linux/kernel/ksyms.c for
`sys_call_table` from being exported properly and later was made static and removed IMU.

Now this has been exported again in of some of latest kernels (in some version > 3.3.x). I would recommend digging into the LXR to check out the details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether your current kernel is compiled with the option CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL=y